# Aurelia - custom element does not inherit binding context by default. Is it okay?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

Each view-model gets two parameters in its `bind()` method: `bindingContext` and `overrideContext`. The first one describes the current scope, the second the outer scope(s): the parent, the parent's parent, etc. This looks something like that:

```
overrideContext: {
    bindingContext: {...}, //current level
    parentOverrideContext: {
        bindingContext: {...}, //parent's binding context
        parentOverrideContext: {...} //and so on
    }
}
```

This lets the view-model access methods and fields from parents' scopes as well.

If a custom element is created, it receives the expected `bindingContext` and `overrideContext` parameters in `bind()`. But when it passes them to its child(ren), it is not in the expected format, but:

```
overrideContext: {
    bindingContext: {...}, //current level, this is ok
    parentOverrideContext: null,
    __parentOverrideContext: {...}, //this is the real
}
```

Note that the original `parentOverrideContext` has been moved to `__parentOverrideContext`. In this way, the templating engine won't be able to resolve anything from the parents' scope. Let's have a concrete example:

*page.html:*

```
<template>
    Hello, user!
    <custom-element-1>
        <custom-element-2>
            <button click.trigger="myHandler()">Call myHandler</button>
        </custom-element-2>
    </custom-element-1>
</template>
```

*page.js:*

```
export class MyPage {
    myHandler() {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Here I'd like to call a method defined on the parent's parent (`MyPage`) from a button in the innermost view-model (`<custom-element-2>`), but due to the different format, the templating cannot find the parent and cannot resolve the method.

After some debugging, I've realized that there is a flag (`instruction.inheritBindingContext`), which determines if the parent should be included or not. The flag is `true` for router-views by default, but `false` for custom elements. The question: Am I not understanding it correctly and **is this the desired behaviour? Or is it a bug?**

Anyway, if someone interested, the flag can be easily changed:

```
import {customElement, processContent} from 'aurelia-templating';

@processContent((compiler, resources, node, instruction) => {
    instruction.inheritBindingContext = true;
    return true/false;
})
@customElement('custom-element-1')
export class CustomElement1 {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional. It prevents developers from building custom elements that are not portable because they rely on specific properties of the outer scope.

https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-custom-element-vs-compose/

Comment: I see that and understand the concept of `bindable`s (though not used in the above example). My real scenario is rather complex, but the reason I'd access the outer scope -- like in the example above -- is to define arbitrary inner content for the custom element, which might have some event triggers. Even though this inner content will be bound to the inner element's context, it feels more natural to bind the event (directly) to the outer scope, since it was defined there, rather than passing a callback along.